# Rolling back Heroku push's and git branches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm Working on a Project were i:

Created a Branch, Merged it with Master, Pushed it to Heroku.
Created another Branch, Merged it with Master, Pushed it to Heroku.
From master pushed another change to Heroku.

When i type Heroku Rollback i get:

```
v103  Deploy 10101010   xxx@gmail.com  2017/11/27 17:53:14 -0500 
v102  Deploy 20202020   xxx@gmail.com  2017/11/27 17:32:04 -0500
v101  Deploy 30303030   xxx@gmail.com  2017/11/27 16:35:01 -0500
v100  Deploy 40404040   xxx@gmail.com  2017/11/19 17:18:31 -0400
```

But i now wanna complete reverse EVERYTHING, including my branches and go back to v100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to [rollback to a specific release](https://blog.heroku.com/releases-and-rollbacks) (i.e v100):

```
$ heroku rollback v100
```

Comment: what do you mean?\

Comment: what about the branches on my local machine? As i've done a rails migration that needs to be reversed. Sorry about the first message.

Comment: i see my commits , and a message that its been rollback, but i sort of wanted to have the commits after 100 just erased. I basically wanna go back to 100 with a clean git and machine. Like i never did anything yesterday.

Comment: you got it. happy coding!